# Set correct orientation to preview camera and final result image

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm developing my custom camera app and I'm having problems with the orientation.

When the phone is in portrait orientation the preview screen and result image shows in landscape

[image]

When the phone is in left landscape orientation the preview screen and result image shows correctly

[image]

When the phone is in right landscape orientation the preview screen and result image shows in landscape mode but flipped vertically

[image]

I've read about changing orientation with setDisplayorientation but I have not managed to fix it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks for the help

This is the code of the camera activity that starts preview

```
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!CAMBIO!!!!!!!!" );
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }


    private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
        if (myCamera!=null && mySurfaceHolder.getSurface()!=null) {
            try {
                myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mySurfaceHolder);
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                        "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                Toast
                .makeText(CameraHandler.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }

            if (!cameraConfigured) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters=myCamera.getParameters();
                Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height,
                        parameters);

                if (size!=null) {

                    parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

                    myCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                    cameraConfigured=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        if (cameraConfigured && myCamera!=null) {
            myCamera.startPreview();
            inPreview=true;
        }
    }

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,  Camera.Parameters parameters) {

        Camera.Size result=null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            System.out.println("Soportados " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
            if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
                if (result==null) {
                    result=size;
                }
                else {
                    int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                    int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                    if (newArea>resultArea) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return(result);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the grammar mistakes.

Comment: same problem with me for orientation I posted my solution in my post Please check it will help you to set orientation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657694/impementation-of-tuch-to-focus-on-camera-in-android

Answer (score 2):

The code sample for [setDisplayorientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) is in the main documentation:

> If you want to make the camera image show in the same orientation as
>   the display, you can use the following code.

```
 public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

> Starting from API level 14, this method can be called when preview
>   is active.

This does not apply to the picture captured with [Camera.takePicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)). For that, you can use [Camera.Parameters.setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)). Unfortunately, some devices only set an EXIF rotation flag according to this, and even more unfortunately, some popular image viewers ignore this flag. In such case, you must rotate the resulting JPEG yourself. For that, you can use a Java [MediaUtil](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/) library, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302674/192373.

Comment: I solve it, `setRotation` must be executed AFTER `setDisplayOrientation`. Thanks